# Wifi hotspot is not working in Ubuntu 20.04 in my desktop

Tags: drivers, realtek-wireless, hot-spot, tp-link

I have s particularly good Lan connection to my desktop. To connect some other devices to the internet, I brought a Tp-link Wi-Fi adapter (Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter). I tried many ways to turn on Wi-Fi hotspot but each time I received an error as "Activation of network connection failed". To make sure that the adapter is working, I tried it using in another windows PC and it is working. The same adapter can be used in my PC to connect to a Wi-Fi network. But it cannot activate the Wi-Fi hotspot in my PC, where the internet is from the LAN connection.
my adapter is: 
Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in Ubuntu 18.04
It was solved by reloading the router, though the signal was very weak.